# how to remove update repo that always fails

Tags: update-manager

A week or so ago I tried to add a new package repo that supposedly had a package I wanted.  Unfortunately, the information about it was out of date, and I found that it fails to connect to it each time.  I'd like to just remove the new repo, but I'm not sure how to do that.

For context, when I update, I get this:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/geod/ppa-geod/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 135.214.42.30 8080]
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/geod/ppa-geod/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 135.214.42.30 8080]
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/geod/ppa-geod/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 135.214.42.30 8080]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open a terminal window (ctrl-alt-t) and run

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

sudo ppa-purge ppa:geod/ppa-geod
```

That should do the trick, and remove the repository along with installed packages.

Yet another way is `sudo add-apt-reposiry -r ppa:geod/ppa-geod`.
That will just remove the repositry.

Alternatively, you can run `software-properties-gtk`, in the window that opens, select the Other Software Tab, find the corresponding lines and delete them.

Comment: I should have tried the "alternatively" first.  The first fails with a chicken/egg problem.  It refuses to remove a repo it can't connect to.  Why the heck isn't that dialog available directly from the update-manager gui?  Wouldn't that make sense?

Comment: One up for alternative method!

Answer (score 15):

If you know the repo error just use `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/REPO-DIST.list`

If you want to check what you've added and then remove from there you always can check with:

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

Then with the command mentioned above.

Comment: after using `sudo ppa-purge <repositoryName>` failed for solving the problem, that answer solved it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the **easy way**:

1. Open the Terminal
2. `sudo software-properties-gtk`
3. Window will open
4. go to "**Other Software**" tab
5. select item from the list that you want to remove
6. Click on **Remove** and you are done. Cheers !!!

Comment: Note: in more recent distros you might need to use `sudo software-properties-qt` instead.